# How to update properties in ASP.NET Core Service (DI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I have the Chatbot, the data for the chatbot is stored in the Azure Cosmos DB. If I change the data in Cosmos DB, I have to restart my web app because the service used for fetching the data from Cosmos is registered in `Startup.cs` as Singleton.

So my requirement is to update the service properties (data) from Cosmos without restarting the app; also it should not lead to a deadlock.

Can anyone help me with the way to achieve this?

Comment: something can only be hook on application startup e.g. CORS policy e.t.c.
In old asp.net we use to put app_offline.htm till the new deployment done. that seems still available as i have seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: It sounds like your CosmosDB client is caching the results of its queries. You shouldn't do that and query the database every time so you get the latest results. That way your client can still be a singleton.

Comment: Does the below answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

> **CosmosClient** provides a client-side logical representation of the Azure Cosmos DB account. This client can be used to configure and
> execute requests in the Azure Cosmos DB database service.
>
> **CosmosClient** is thread-safe. It's recommended to maintain a single instance of **CosmosClient** per lifetime of the application which
> enables efficient connection management and performance.

CosmosDB Client will **get the data that is actually present in the database** unless you are caching it. Moreover, make sure, you are using the right [consistency level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels) and [redundancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability).

Comment: Does this help you?